# How can filter for specific keywords in extracted tweets?

Tags: python, twitter, data-analysis

I have a code that gives me the tweets from my timeline on Twitter and saves them to a CSV. How can I make it search and save only tweets that contain a specific keyword X?

The code is below:

```
access_token = config['twitter']['access_token']
access_token_secret = config['twitter']['access_token_secret']

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_key_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

public_tweets = api.home_timeline()
data = []

for tweet in public_tweets:
    data.append([tweet.created_at, tweet.user.screen_name, tweet.text])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python provides the `in` operator for words in strings, so you don't have to use regex or something more involved than a simple `if`, as per the following:

```py
query_string = "word" # your keyword

for tweet in public_tweets:
    if query_string in tweet.text:
        data.append([tweet.created_at, tweet.user.screen_name, tweet.text])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked very well :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to check `if keyword in tweet.text`, but you'll get false positives (e.g. `baseball` will match if `keyword='ball'`). The better approach can use regex:

```py
import tweepy
import configparser
import pandas as pd
import re

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
api_key = config['twitter']['api_key']
api_key_secret = config['twitter']['api_key_secret']
access_token = config['twitter']['access_token']
access_token_secret = config['twitter']['access_token_secret']

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_key_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

public_tweets = api.home_timeline()

columns = ['Time', 'User', 'Tweet']

keywords = ['foo', 'bar']
regex = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(keywords) + r')\b')
data = [[tweet.created_at, tweet.user.screen_name, tweet.text]
        for tweet in public_tweets
        if regex.search(tweet.text)]
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df.to_csv('Tweets.csv')
```

Here `\b` refers to word boundary and `|` separates words in group. So we search for *any* of keywords if they're not part of some larger word. `re.compile` is used only to speed things up and not to recompile it for every iteration. List comprehension is just more readable IMO comparing to `.append()` in a loop (and also faster).